# Quick text editor from within shell environment

Tags: shell, command-line, editor

I sometimes want to make small edits to small file from within the shell I'm working in, while looking at my command history.

As an example, if I want to write a short shell script after experimenting on the command line, I can do:

```
cat > example.sh
```

and work from what I can see.

But cat's not the best editor. If I use vi or emacs though (as far as I can tell) the whole environment changes, and I can only see what I've been doing is if I run the shell history command from inside the editor, which isn't really what I want either.

I realise this is really nit-picky, but does anyone have any suggestions for a sensible editor (or way of using a sensible editor) that I can quickly invoke from the command-line and doesn't spawn its own environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to edit the command line, have a look at the (built-in) `fc` editor (Bourne Shells).

If you need to edit files though, nothing beats a real editor. You can use [The Standard](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html) (`ed`, man!) or what everybody else *should* be using, `vi` :-)

Unlike `vi`, `ed` does not clear the screen; in fact, it is a line oriented editor. Note that some versions of `vi` in some terminals (`vim` in an `xterm`) can be configured to save the screen and restore it upon exit as it was before editing.

Answer (score 2):

Try a terminal multiplexer like [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (or [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)). It will allow you to quickly split your terminal (horizontally or vertically) into another "pane" and you can then start `vi` in the new pane. You will still be able to see the rest of your shell in the other pane. I do this all the time.